# Can I remove possible duplicate links if I think they are wrong?

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-questions

For a question I asked awhile back and received what I believe to be a incorrect possible duplicate. I'm assuming that these votes came from not reading the question or not understanding the question. Perhaps my question was not clear enough:

[Here is the question I'm referring to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26949187/how-exactly-does-javascipts-data-type-convertion-work-for-operator)

This has two close-votes links to a question about [what is the `!!` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript). In my question the only real reference it has is that I'm using that to convert items into Booleans, to show variables indeed convert to be true. But the question does not ask what it is, and is not relevant to the actual question. It seems to me about equivalent to linking to a question that ask what an *if-statement* is because one is used in the question.

What should I do about possible duplicates that I believe are incorrect or irrelevant to the asked question? Would it be worth it to attempt removing incorrect ones?

Comment: You can't "remove" those votes. If they are collecting, and you still believe it's not a duplicate, what you should do is edit/comment about exactly why it's not a duplicate.

Comment: As it's told in the dupe message, you can edit your question, clarify why you thing the duplicate isn't applying, and flag for reopening.

Comment: @AndrewBarber I did comment saying why it's not a duplicate.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek _" I did comment saying why ..."_ It's clearly stated you should improve/edit your question.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ To be fair, I said "edit/comment"; I probably should have said edit. Though, I think you are talking about the "Closed as Duplicate" message. D'oh!

Comment: Reading through the question, it looks like one of the proposed duplicates *is* an appropriate duplicate, and it answers the exact question that you're asking.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Ah, I see. I didn't check the question in question. But just answered from 1st glance here. The question isn't yet closed, thus a comment for clarification might be enough.

Comment: @AndrewBarber I'm not really interested in removing the votes, more on the message itself at the top of the question seems misleading to me.

Comment: @Servy The other one is not a duplicate question, but haves related answer. Although the 5th answer addresses the issue in their answer most of them do no. Asking how `==` works in a certain case is not the same thing as asking the comparison between `==` and `===`, I think they are indeed closely related, but not exactly duplicates.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek The message you are talking about 1) says "possible", and 2) is only visible to you. Mods can't even see it. It's just so the poster of the question sees it clearly. (it was often being ignored).

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek If the other question answers your question then it's a suitable duplicate.  That there are differences in the question not relevant to the answer [by definition] isn't relevant.

Answer (score 5):

You can edit the question to clarify in what way it is different from the proposed duplicates, and why the answer(s) to the proposed duplicate don't answer your question.  Even if that information is there, if people are still thinking that it is a duplicate, those points may not be clear enough, or not given proper emphasis.

You can also reply to the comments explaining why you feel that those answers don't answer your question.

Comment: Yup; and in such a case, there is no need to "remove" the votes. If you've made your case well, no more votes will come in, and those there will sit there until they expire.